# Instagram Bot that DMs Users on Post Like

Tags: python, web, instagram

Okey so what im trying to do is that if a user is liking a post from my instagram account this user is getting a dm like "Thank you for your Like if you enjoy my content consider following". Is this possible via code or any website?

Comment: Consider looking [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'm fairly certain that this would be considered spam and lead to your account being blocked...